# Wrapping processing.js in Google Web Toolkit

Tags: gwt, visualization, processing.js

I was wondering whether anyone has managed to wrap John Resig's [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) library in Google Web Toolkit (maybe in combination with GWT Canvas) or knows of any resources or sample code out on the web. Processing.js is extremely powerful for generating bespoke data visualisations, custom animations etc (I am aware of the Google Visualisation API). I'd be grateful for any help and/or pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the question is outdated, but leaving it unanswered won't make me happier :)
One of the libraries out there is called [processing-js-gwt](https://github.com/timeu/processing-js-gwt,)